# Google line chart overlapping tooltip

Tags: jquery, tooltip, google-visualization

I've designed a graphing application using the google charts api. Below is an example graph I draw using the data. As you can see there are two graphs in the image. when I hover on a graph a tool tip appears with the relevant data! it's standard bt the problem is when the two graphs overlap, I can only view the tooltip of the graph that's drawn infront! how can I make the tool tip show the data from the graph that is beneath the first graph.?

[image]

Comment: I suppose if you can detect where the lines will overlap at the time you build the chart data, you could [include a column for custom tooltip content](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content).

Answer (score 4):

You can set `focusTarget` to `"category"` which will highlight all series at that X point and show them in the tooltip so that even overlaps will display both data points. See more on that option [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?csw=1#Configuration_Options).

You can alternatively [add noise to the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077155/add-noise-to-chart-google-charts-api/19084978#19084978) to dither the results so that overlaps don't display as overlaps.

Comment: This really wotked.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event listener and retrieve the values of both charts at the same time and then add them to a custom tooltip as it was suggested in the comments:

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById("myChart");
    var listener = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (e) {
                     console.log(e);
                  });
```

That should help you get started.